# VBA conditional formatting if it is less than TODAY

Tags: excel, vba

I want to do VBA to turn cells in red if cell's date value is less than today. It should also look for blank cell dates and don't touch it. I don't want to use conditional formatting instead of VBA, I want it to use Macros.

```
Sub ChangeColor()

    Dim rCell As Range

    With Sheet1
        For Each rCell In .Range("$C$2:$AG$27", .Cells(.Rows.Count, 11).End(xlUp)).Cells
            If rCell.Value > Date Then
                rCell.Interior.Color = vbRed
            Else
                rCell.Interior.Color = vbGreen
            End If
        Next rCell
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Taking a [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) or reading about [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and incorporating the information there will go a long to getting some real help on this site. As written you have simply told us information. There is no question nor any code that is not working.

Comment: Why would you want to use VBA for this instead of the built in conditional formatting?  It's almost always better to use built in tools wherever possible.  Also, this is not a code writing service, we help you correct errors or issues you encounter in your code, so please provide what you have tried so far and what's not working about it.  If you're just looking a place to start, look into the [Range.Interior](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196598.aspx) object (specifically the Range.Interior.ColorIndex method)

Comment: Check top please forgot to attach code

Comment: Now tell us what the code is doing that is incorrect. What errors and on what line?

Comment: For dates and currency always use `Value2` change to ` rCell.Value2 < Date `

Comment: It should look for today's date and change only the ones less than today's date and don't touch other cells which could be blank or have other values  greater than today's date

Comment: Your goal: _"I want to do VBA to turn cells in red if cell's date value is **less than today**."_ Your code: _If **rCell.Value > Date** Then rCell.Interior.Color = vbRed_. I wish I could brag but this happens to me all too often as well...

Answer (score 0):

Okay give it a try.

The code will apply the red interior color to the cells which contain a date prior to today's date.
It will not touch any other cells.

```
Sub ChangeColor()
    Dim rCell As Range
    With Sheet1
        For Each rCell In .Range("$C$2:$AG$27", .Cells(.Rows.Count, 11).End(xlUp)).Cells
            If rCell <> "" And IsDate(rCell) And rCell.Value < Date Then
                rCell.Interior.Color = vbRed
            End If
        Next rCell
    End With
End Sub
```